# Jquery check element tag name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JQuery:

```
$('.one').addClass('two');
```

I need to add the class `two` only if the element of class `one` is a list item `li`. How do I do this?

Comment: How about `$('li.one') ...`

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
$('li.one').addClass('two');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery [is()](https://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
if($('.one').is('li')){
    $('.one').addClass('two');
}
```

or alternatively, in one line

```
$('li.one').addClass('two');
```

This will select **only** `li` elements of class `one` and nothing else

Answer (score 1):

You could also try:

`$("li.one").addClass("two");`

All `li` elements that have a class `one` will have the class `two` added.